# What is the visualization of light according to Maxwell's theory of Electromagnetic wave?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, visualization

The theory must imply a visualization. I am not being able to think or find any.
I know the sine wave representation. But light obviously not goes like a physical string. right?

Comment: It is a vector field (or two actually).  Difficult to draw, but this is something I made: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PlaneVectorWave.gif  This one by someone else is very good: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Linear_Polarization_Linearly_Polarized_Light_plane_wave.svg

Comment: Someone had downvoted the question, but I think it is an excellent one. I have asked masters students in electrical engineering this question, and most could not answer. Or gave wrong answers (about photons moving up and down, for example).

Comment: "Theory must imply a visualization."$^{[\text{citation needed}]}$

Answer (score 1):

Light has two vector field components. An electric field $(\vec{E})$ and a magnetic field $(\vec{B})$ component. $(\vec{E})$ and $(\vec{B})$ components are perpendicular to each other and to the propagation of light. [Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/EM-Wave.gif)  is a visual representation of the electromagnetic wave.

Comment: well i know that. but light obviously doesn't go like a physical string.

Comment: You're right, @Touhid that light doesn't work like a string, but the mathematics that we use to describe strings also works for other types of waves and oscillations, like light. That's why we use these to visualise light waves. The vectors show the amplitude and polarity of the electric and magnetic fields, rather than the displacement of the string.